# How do I show an empty preferences category in Android?

Tags: android-fragments, android-preferences

I have a use case in which I have to show an empty preference category. I have tries setting the visibility flag value to `true` but the preference category does not seem to be displayed.

This is my logic

```
public class MyFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();

        // ViewModelProviderFactory instance is injected using Dagger.
        NotificationsViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), viewModelProviderFactory)
        .get(NotificationsViewModel.class);

       final SwitchPreferenceCompat notificationsEnabledPreference = preferencesFactory.create(
        screen,
        SwitchPreferenceCompat.class,
        NotificationsViewModel.MASTER_SWITCH_PREFERENCE_KEY,
        R.string.preferences_enable_notifications);

        final PreferenceCategory orderUpdatesCategory = preferencesFactory.create(
        screen,
        PreferenceCategory.class,
        NotificationsViewModel.ORDER_UPDATES_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE_KEY,
        R.string.notifications_group_order_updates,
        NotificationsViewModel.MASTER_SWITCH_PREFERENCE_KEY
    );
    orderUpdatesCategory.setVisible(true);


        . . . .  Some other logic ... 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootTag)
    {
        final PreferenceManager preferenceManager = 
        getPreferenceManager();
        final PreferenceScreen screen = 
            preferenceManager.createPreferenceScreen(
                preferenceManager.getContext());
       setPreferenceScreen(screen);
    }
}
```

Helper function PreferenceFactory#create

```
public <T extends Preference> T create(@NonNull PreferenceGroup parent, @NonNull Class<T> classInstance,
    @Nullable String key, @StringRes int titleResId, @NonNull String dependencyKey)
{
    final T preference = create(classInstance);
    if (parent.addPreference(preference))
    {
        preference.setKey(key);
        preference.setTitle(titleResId);
        preference.setDependency(dependencyKey);
    }

    return preference;
}
```

How can I show the empty preference category?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what preferencesFactory is since it's not initialized in the code above and is not part of the PreferenceFragmentCompat API.
I was able to do what you wanted to do (display an empty Category) by adding categories and preferences to a PreferenceScreen object, as shown in the sample code here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/programmatic-hierarchy

Comment: This is just a helper function that we have created. I have updated the code block with the function body. The PreferenceFactory is injected using Dagger.

Comment: I don't see where you are adding the preference (or PreferenceCategory) to PreferenceScreen, which is a requirement. Please check out the code in that link above

Comment: It is added in the helper function in this line `if (parent.addPreference(preference))`. The parent in this example is the PreferenceScreen object.

Comment: Which version of preferences are you using? I assume the AndroidX (support library) version, since it's PreferenceFragmentCompat, but worth checking. The platform version has been deprecated and may not have the functionality you need.

Comment: Also, it's worth playing with your code to remove the variables - try it without dependency injection. The basic functionality you are seeking works on my side, it's pretty straightforward. But I'm not able to reproduce whatever you're doing since I don't have the DI side set up.

Comment: btw, my version is: androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01